# Not able to add wp8 platform in cordova app

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, platform, phonegap

I am trying to add wp8 platform in my cordova app but when I run the command :

```
cordova platform add wp8
```

source: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/wp8/

It shows error message as below:

```
Error: Failed to fetch platform wp8
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.3.9600
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "wp8" "--save"
npm ERR! node v6.10.1
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code E404

npm ERR! 404 Registry returned 404 for GET on https://registry.npmjs.org/wp8
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'wp8' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)

npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     D:\Projects\hello\node_modules\npm-debug.log
```

Comment: `Probably this is either a connection problem` I think this is your case. For me it is working. Sometimes the `npm registry` is not available. Keep trying…

Comment: I try to check https://registry.npmjs.org/wp8 and it is showing nothing. if we check https://registry.npmjs.org/android or https://registry.npmjs.org/ios it shows proper json data but for wp8 it showing empty {}

Comment: The packages in the registry you found are not the same as `cordova` provides. They can be found by `cordova-ios`, `cordova-android` or even `cordova-wp8`…

Answer (score 1):

`wp8` platform was dropped in cordova@7: [JIRA issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-13131?jql=labels%20%3D%20wp8)

With cordova@7 you have to use `windows` platform:

```
cordova platform add windows
cordova build windows -- --appx=8.1-phone
```

Answer (score 0):

Need a 64-bit version of Windows 8 Pro, either an installation disk or an ISO disk image file. The Pro version is necessary to run the device emulator.