# Cordova error -> failed to fetch platform wp8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8.1

Error: Failed to fetch platform wp8
Probably this is either a connection problem, or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: wp8@latest

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45137054/not-able-to-add-wp8-platform-in-cordova-app